# Can't edit beziercurve, handles are not visible

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

Using blender 2.90.1 i'm trying to make a knot using a bezier curve.
Suddenly I can no longer edit my bezier curve. In edit mode the handles are not shown (see screenshot).
My overlays are turned on and I restarted blender multiple times without a succes. I also tried copy pasting in a new blender file but this also didn't help.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: here is the blend file:
[image]

[image: In edit mode: the handles are not shown. I can't edit it]

Comment: Just looked at it in 2.83. Try using <ALT> H in edit mode and see if they appear.

Comment: You've hidden everything.  Select your curve, enter edit, hit alt h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [John Eason](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198820/cant-edit-beziercurve-handles-are-not-vissible#comment332927_198820) and [Nathan](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/198820/cant-edit-beziercurve-handles-are-not-vissible#comment332928_198820) said in the comments: unhiding in selection mode solves the problem.

In case others have the same problem here is how to solve it:
first select your bezier curve, then go to edit mode and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select everything. To unhide press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>